# Override version of Maven plugin used in parent pom to new version in main pom

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

Working on multi-module maven project. Have `maven-compiler-plugin` used in parent pom as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>${java.version}</source>
      <target>${java.version}</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Want to use `<version>3.1</version>` in the main project pom due to its incremental compile support. Do not have write access in parent pom. How can i just configure plugin in main project pom to use new version?

Comment: Just define a `<build><pluginManagement><plugins>..</plugins></pluginManagement></build>` block in your project and just give groupId/artifactId/version (where I left `..`) (new version of course).. No need to define other things.Apart from that I would strongly recommend to upgrade to most recent version of maven-compiler-plugin (3.8.1)... see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Answer (score 1):

You can override the plugin in submodule

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>${java.version}</source>
      <target>${java.version}</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: in `<pluginManagemnt>` or in `plugins` secction

Comment: Pluginmgmt  is intended to configure project builds that inherit from this one... so I would say plugins here

Comment: @CodeScale `<pluginManagement>` can be used to simply override the version for a plugin. The given example overrides things which don't need to be overwritten. So that's the reason for pluginManagement.

Comment: @khmarbaise pluginmgmt should be used on the parent pom.xml and I agree with that. But for submodules I just said that using plugins seems better to override parent plugin definition